# How to build a RPM package with custom changes

Tags: linux, rpmbuild

I'm working on Linux.
I have installed a ruby rpm on my system sing following command,

```
rpm –ivh zenith_ruby_1.8.6-1.0-2.el5.src.rpm
```

Now i have added some debugging statments in the source files of this rpm
and i want to rebuild this rpm with my changes in source file.

I tried using following command

```
rpmbuild -ba rpmbuild/SPECS/zenith_ruby-1.8.6-p369.spec
```

But execution of this commands leads to overwriting the source file that cause removal of by changes from source file.
Is there any way to re-build with our changes in source file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for above problem.

We need to execute following command to build already installed RPM :

```
rpmbuild -bc --short-circuit rpmbuild/SPECS/zenith_ruby-1.8.6-p369.spec
```

Answer (score 1):

You should make your changes a patch that gets applied during the build process.
See this [tutorial for instructions](http://bradthemad.org/tech/notes/patching_rpms.php)

Comment: And *please* be sure to add something to the release ID to indicate that it is your patchset and not stock!